# laravel toSql not returning output

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, datatables

I am trying to display details from 2 MySQL tables in a datatable. I tried setting each get to a separate variable and returning them as part of the collection. it returns the first variable but not the second as if it is being ignored.

therefore I have opted to attempt to join the tables but this fails also there is likely something wrong with the join statement as when I try and run ->toSql to output the sql statement the query creates it does not return anything.

here is my script :

```
    class CRUDController extends BaseController {

    public function instances(){




      $query = EC2Instance::select('instance_id',


                        'public_dns_name',
                        'key_name',
                        'instance_type',
                        'launch_time'

                        )->get();

    $c_num= Account::select('aws_account_id'
                        )->get();



return Datatable::collection ($query,$c_num)


    ->addColumn('instance_id', function($model){
        return $model->instance_id ;
        })

    ->addColumn('public_dns_name', function($model){
        return  $model->public_dns_name;

    })
     ->addColumn('key_name', function($model){
        return  $model->key_name;

    })

     ->addColumn('instance_type', function($model){
        return  $model->instance_type;

    })
     ->addColumn('launch_time', function($model){
        return $model->launch_time; 
    })

      ->addColumn('aws_account_id', function($model){
        return  $model->aws_account_id;
     })


        ->searchColumns('instance_id',
                        'public_dns_name',
                        'key_name',
                        'instance_type',
                        'launch_time'


                        )

        ->orderColumns('instance_id',

                        'instance_type',
                        'public_dns_name',
                        'key_name',
                        'launch_time'


                        )
        ->make();
}
}
```

the above shows setting each variable separately.

here is the envisaged equivalent join statement

```
 $query = DB::table('ec2_instance')->join('aws_account','aws_account.id','=','ec2_instance.id')->select('ec2_instance.instance_id','ec2_instance.public_dns_name','ec2_instance.key_name','ec2_instance.instance_type','ec2_instance.launch_time','aws_account.aws_account_id')->toSql();
```

note I am joining on id in each table which is not to be displayed thanks

Comment: Try with `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the sql was wrong nothing was being returned